# How to get NLTK sentence tokenizer read a column in a file

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I'm a newbie to Python and started playing with NLTK this evening.

I've read in a file with pandas and now trying to call one column, the description. I'm hitting a problem with the code because it was originally written to call a bit of text in script.

I've tried to amend it but think I've broken it. Code and errors below

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",")
#data.head()

datatext = data['Description']
#datatext.head()

import nltk
from nameparser import HumanName
#nltk.download()

def get_human_names(datatext):
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(datatext.read())
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    sentt = nltk.ne_chunk(pos, binary = False)
    person_list = []
    person = []
    name = ""
    for subtree in sentt.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'PERSON'):
        for leaf in subtree.leaves():
            person.append(leaf[0])
        if len(person) > 1: #avoid grabbing lone surnames
            for part in person:
                name += part + ' '
            if name[:-1] not in person_list:
                person_list.append(name[:-1])
            name = ''
        person = []

    return (person_list)

text = datatext

names = get_human_names(datatext)
print "LAST, FIRST"
for name in names: 
    last_first = HumanName(name).last + ', ' + HumanName(name).first
print last_first
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-2f6ec1c0b04c> in <module>()
     21 text = datatext
     22 
---> 23 names = get_human_names(datatext)
     24 print "LAST, FIRST"
     25 for name in names:

<ipython-input-18-2f6ec1c0b04c> in get_human_names(datatext)
      1 def get_human_names(datatext):
----> 2     tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(datatext.read())
      3     pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
      4     sentt = nltk.ne_chunk(pos, binary = False)
      5     person_list = []

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   2358                 return self[name]
   2359             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 2360                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   2361 
   2362     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete: the definition of `datatext` is not shown. However, this variable appears to point to a Pandas `Series` object, which doesn't have a `read()` method – hence the exception. Instead, extract the relevant field (using subscript or so). Note: `word_tokenize()` expects a single sentence.

Comment: Ah, word_tokenize() might not fit my needs. Is there a method for going through a series of data?

Comment: Well, what's in the data? If you want to POS tag and chunk a text, you need to tokenise it in any case. Iterating over the elements of a `Series` object is probably done with a simple `for` loop (but I'm not familiar with Pandas). I suspect that your problem has nothing to do with NLTK, but with Pandas instead.

Comment: It's description of social pages. I'm trying to see if I can identify names from it and create a new series of data with first and last names. Are you suggesting that I don't need to use pandas?

Comment: No, I'm just asking questions. If your text data aren't tokenised, then you need to do that (it seems your are trying already). If you have more than one sentence per data point, you need to do sentence splitting first. Speaking of which: I just realised that your title says "sentence tokenizer", but there's nothing about it in the body of your post.

Comment: I will tweak this and let you know how I get on.